# Android hierarchyviewer unable to load window data

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the hierarchyviewer tool to see the layout of my Android app.

I can run hierarchyviewer, and see the emulator running. I click on `<Focused Window>` and try to load the view hierarchy and get the error:

> Unable to load window data for window `<Focused Window>` on device emulator-5554.

I'm developing on OSX (10.6.5) using Eclipse 3.5.2. I'm currently debugging through Eclipse, in a custom-sized emulator. I have updated the Android tools to the latest (revision 8) with the AVD and SDK manager in Eclipse. I haven't found any threads searching for the error message, or for general heirarchy viewer problems.

Does anyone have an idea how to get the tool working?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you have the solution for this??

Answer (score 36):

I found an application's view hierarchy does not load when the the app is under debug. Have you tried dismissing the debugger and just starting the app from the launch icon?

Comment: I have the same problem, and my app is not under debug.  It is just running on the emulator.

Comment: It's not necessary to restart the app, stopping the debugger from eclipse solves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: or closing eclipse also helps

Comment: Had same problem with android studio and genymotion virtual device. Stopping task in android studio and running in manually from emulator apps helped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: after years and years.., this answers helped me!

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was a *carriage return* character (U+000D) in one of my TextViews which prevented the hierarchyviewer from loading the window data.

These thinks do not help in this case:

- cleaning the project
- deploying the app not in debug-mode
- closing eclipse
- running `adb kill-server && adb start-server`
- trying other views like com.android.settings.Settings or com.android.development.Development (which worked fine)

Comment: Removing "\r" symbol from textviews helped me

Answer (score 2):

For mac add `~/work/android-sdk/tools$ ANDROID_HVPROTO=ddm monitor`

or steps outlined here: http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/hierarchy-viewer/setup.html

Answer (score 1):

Problem is it only support Only Gingerbread and higher. https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/tree/browse_frm/thread/b8aac9fe39ec1941

Answer (score -7):

For me, adding the INTERNET uses-permission to the manifest solved the problem:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: +1 It's likely you're using the [ViewServer](https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer/) class which _does_ require the internet permission. However this is not a valid answer to OP's question because this class isn't needed to run Hierarchy Viewer on emulators. +1 because it might be helpful to others.