# no rendering time info in android hierarchyviewer

Tags: android, android-emulator

[image]

Hi, I try to follow android's [Debugging and Profilling UI](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-ui.html#viewhierarchy) article and started the hierarchyviewer.

I am following the steps in the tutorial:

1. start emulator
2. start app
3. open cmd and start hierarchyviewer
4. select my activity and wait. The application is the spinner sample from SDK samples.

However, all rendering time related info are n/a, no measure time, no layoutime, no drawtime, no color circles, as show in the screen shot.

I also tried to exit eclipse because [some info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626767/android-hierarchyviewer-unable-to-load-window-data) said debugger may causing problem but nothing changed.

am I missing any thing?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, this only works from Android 2.3 onwards

(see https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/tree/browse_frm/thread/b8aac9fe39ec1941)