# Android Hierarchy Viewer Unable to load window data on device emulator. String index out of range 173

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

In the hierarchy viewer I get this cryptic error messages when I try to inspect views.

```
[2013-10-19 18:15:42 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to load window data for window com.example/com.example.app.home.HomeActivity on device emulator-5554
[2013-10-19 18:15:42 - hierarchyviewer]String index out of range: 173
```

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: Have you tryed this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626767/android-hierarchyviewer-unable-to-load-window-data ?

Answer (score 0):

Removing "\r" symbol from textviews helped me.