# how can eclipse tell me in which activity i'm currently in?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, android-activity

I try to debug my android app and I see a redundant blank activity sometimes.

However I cannot understand the flow which leads me to that blank activity.

How can eclipse help me understand which Activity is displayed?

I have looked at the DDMS perspective and have found no answer.

Also tried to press "pause" run (debug play, stop and pause buttons)

and i couldn't see where to read the current active activity.

Does someone know?

**update**

I have tried

```
adb logcat | grep "ActivityManager"

    D/dalvikvm(28517): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 192 unimplemented (abstract) methods
    W/ApplicationsProvider(27925):  at android.app.ActivityManager.getAllPackageUsageStats(ActivityManager.java:2520)
    D/dalvikvm(28691): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 192 unimplemented (abstract) methods
    W/ApplicationsProvider(27925):  at android.app.ActivityManager.getAllPackageUsageStats(ActivityManager.java:2520)
    W/ApplicationsProvider(27925):  at android.app.ActivityManager.getAllPackageUsageStats(ActivityManager.java:2520)
    E/Parcel  (27354):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:4066)
    E/Parcel  (27354):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:3964)
    E/Parcel  (27354):  at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:159)
    E/Parcel  (27354):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2645)
```

but where do I see the Activity name?

[image]

**update 2**

I have tried to open hierarchy view but it has an error inspecting my app:

[image]

**update 3**

I cannot see it even in the log cat

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes u can log ur activity which you are currently IN :

```
adb logcat | grep "ActivityManager"
```

Below is ScreenShot showing activity with package name :

[image]

Comment: yes. using mac. where should I have used it otherwise?

Comment: hmm , what comes when u do adb devices in ur mac command propmt?

Comment: List of devices attached 
4df1250c1d449f4d device

Comment: I see, but it's different than mine

Comment: once u navigate on device u can see logcat populating with ur package name followed by activity name

Comment: "navigate towards u app" what does that mean?

Comment: `W/ActivityManager(14561): Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.example.manyexampleapp/com.zoomer.ifs.AppService } U=0: not found`

Comment: i navigate through my app but see nothing in the logcat

Comment: hmm u doing something wronfg i guess

Answer (score 0):

use hierarchy viewer and observe the bold text which describes currently visible activity.To open hierarchy viewer from eclipse,select Window -> Open Perspective -> Hierarchy View.

[image: using hierarchy viewer for currently visible activity]

To learn more about hierarchy viewer refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html)

Comment: hierarchy viewer is part of eclipse?

Comment: I have tried to open hierarchy view but it has an error inspecting my app

Comment: @user1065869 refer https://forums.pragprog.com/forums/152/topics/12024 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626767/android-hierarchyviewer-unable-to-load-window-data and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325051/android-emulator-in-adt-plugin-not-running to solve this issue